# onRestoreInstanceState() is not restoring value

Tags: android, performance

I want to restore value of `finalText`and show it in `TextView` when the device rotate but `finalText` is not restoring it's value. i have set Default value for `finalText` to check if it show instead. `finalText` is the variable in `onActivityResult()`, so i want to restore the values i got as a result from other activity.

```
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "EXTRA_MESSAGE";
public static final String REQUEST_RESULT = "REQUEST_RESULT";
public static final String KEY_COUNTER = "COUNTER";
private String finalText = "Default";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onClick(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, secondActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
    String text = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, text);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int comingFrom, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(comingFrom, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        finalText = Integer.toString(comingFrom) + Integer.toString(data.getIntExtra(REQUEST_RESULT, 0)) + resultCode;
        textView.setText(finalText);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString(KEY_COUNTER, finalText);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    finalText = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_COUNTER);
}
```

Comment: You can get  finalText in onCreate() method too.

Comment: @Nishant Bhakta you want to make that textView display "Default" when it rotates ? or keep the value that you got from on activityResult

Comment: @Charuක No, i want to make textView to display the value which `onActivityResult` receive as a result from another activity. i just set "Default" to check what it display "Default" or the value it received as result. but neither of them being displayed. i am learning android myself.

Comment: @ChetanJoshi Can you please elaborate. i am new to android, started to learn.

Comment: onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState), use savedInstanceState object to get stored value same as you try to get in onRestoreInstanceState () method onCreate() method executes first then onRestoreInstanceState () will be executed

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
TextView textView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  finalText = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_COUNTER);
  textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  textView.setText(finalText);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int comingFrom, int resultCode, Intent data){
  super.onActivityResult(comingFrom, resultCode, data);
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
    finalText = Integer.toString(comingFrom) + Integer.toString(data.getIntExtra(REQUEST_RESULT, 0)) + resultCode;
    textView.setText(finalText);
  }
}
```

Comment: should i need to add `onSaveInstacesState` and `onRestoreInstancesStare` in this class.

Comment: ya sure, you have to retain the field. I didn't add those because there is not change in those methods